# Error in building docker image with perl installation

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and i am trying to build the docker image with the perl installation but not sure exactly how to fix this error.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux

RUN mkdir /shared
RUN cd /shared


RUN yum -y install sudo
RUN cd /shared
RUN echo "Installing Perl."
RUN sudo yum -y update; yum -y install gcc
RUN yum -y install wget
RUN wget http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
RUN cd perl-5.22.1
RUN /shared/perl-5.22.1/Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl-5.22.1/localperl
RUN make
RUN make test
RUN make install
RUN echo "Perl installation complete."
```

instead of /shared/perl-5.22.1/Configure i tried to give ./configure as well but i get the same error No such file or directory

Error:

```
/bin/sh: /shared/perl-5.22.1/Configure: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c /shared/perl-5.22.1/Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl-5.22.1/localperl' returned a non-zero code: 127
ish-mac:testanalyse ish$
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Dockerfile` `RUN` command runs in its own shell. So, when you do something like `RUN cd /shared`, the subsequent `RUN` commands will not be run inside that working directory.

What you want to use in this case is the `WORKDIR` instruction (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir). You can also combine and shorten some things by taking advantage of the `ADD` instruction. A more concise `Dockerfile` to do what you are after might be:

```
FROM amazonlinux
WORKDIR /shared
RUN yum -y install gcc
ADD http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.1.tar.gz /shared
RUN tar -xzf perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
RUN /shared/perl-5.22.1/Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl-5.22.1/localperl
RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1
RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1 test
RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1 install
```

For example, the build context is already running as root so there is no need for `sudo`. With `ADD` we can add directly from URLs and no `wget` is required. And the `make` utility has a `-C` option to specify the working directory for `make`.

This should get you closer to what you are after. But the build still fails for other reasons (which you should probably open another question for if you are stuck).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it fails in make command says no makefile found. Step 17/20 : RUN make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1/
 ---> Running in 2766b0c8e9a5
make: Entering directory `/shared/perl-5.22.1'
make: Leaving directory `/shared/perl-5.22.1'
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
The command '/bin/sh -c make -C /shared/perl-5.22.1/' returned a non-zero code: 2

Comment: You are past the initial question. I would open a new question for this problem if you cannot solve it. It sounds like the configure script is failing before this or the folders are still not correct.